# Best way to efficiently store (and be able to filter by) hashes in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, hash, python-3.5, models

I'm trying to create a Django app where I can look up the hash of a file (md5, sha1, or sha256) in order to get back attributes of that file. Currently, I'm struggling with making a decision on how to efficiently store those values in the database.

I've seen Django's BinaryField, but unfortunately, that appears geared towards purely storage of a password (hash), and the documentation explicitly mentions that you cannot filter on that field when dealing with a QuerySet. This however, is of critical importance for my application. I've seen another post on SA regarding storing MD5 hashes specifically, where it is called out (with good performance numbers) that Django's UUIDField is a perfect fit. However, a UUIDField doesn't support more than 16 bytes, and so doesn't work for SHA1 or SHA256 hashes.

I've looked online to see if someone has come up with a Custom Field implementation for this but came up dry. Does anyone have a good idea on how to proceed? I'm specifically trying to avoid storing the hash as (say) base64 or the hexstring equivalent (using a CharField); I want to just store the bytes of the hash. It seems strange to me that I can't simply store 20 or 32 raw bytes into the database and be able to filter on that.

Thanks in advance! Let me know if there is any more information I can provide.

EDIT: I am using Postgresql as the backend, and python3.